# C++\CLI, обратиться к строке в ListView

Tags: listview, select, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток. Назрел вопрос: как обратиться к выделенной строке в ListView?

Пока надумал костыльную версию обращения:

```
for (int i(0); i < this->listView1->Items->Count; i++) 
{
    if (this->listView1->Items[i]->Selected)
    {
        // сделать что-то
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this->listView1->SelectedItems`?

Comment: А как с ним взаимодействовать? Т.е. получить доступ к Items и к Subitems?

Comment: `this->listView1->SelectedItems[...]`, `this->listView1->SelectedItems[...].SubItems[...]`?

Comment: В том-то и беда, как узнать индекс - я не знаю.

Comment: Индекс элемента? Ну так в массиве `SelectedItems` находятся все выделенные элементы. Если же `MultiSelect == false`, то элемент в массиве будет максимум один.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Забыл про MultiSelect. Сам додумал, как узнать, выделена ли строка. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @Arhad почему не как ответ?

Comment: @Nikita, исправлено :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проход по всему `ListView` не нужен. Готовый список всех выделенных элементов можно получить с помощью свойства `SelectedItems`: `this->listView1->SelectedItems`.

По умолчанию `ListView` позволяет выделять сразу несколько элементов. Чтобы запретить множественное выделение, необходимо задать свойству `MultiSelect` значение `false`. Тогда в массиве `SelectedItems` будет либо ноль, либо один элемент, в зависимости от наличия выделения в списке:

```
// Ссылка на выделенный элемент (или nullptr при отсутствии выделения)
ListView::SelectedListViewItemCollection::Item^ item;

if(this->listView1->SelectedItems->Count > 0)
    item = this->listView1->SelectedItems[0];
else
    item = nullptr;
```

Для получения доступа к `Items` и `Subitems` необходимо обратиться к соответствующему свойству: `item.SubItems[...]`.